# scipy.signal.fftconvolve along only one axis: how can it be done?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I want to filter my signal with 1D kernel using `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` (`'full'` type).

But alas, sometimes I have multidimensional array that should also be filtered by 1D filter (along some specified axis).

I am currently using this code:

```
if len(original_shape) == 0:
    raise ValueError("in_signal should be an array, not scalar")
elif len(original_shape) == 1:
    out_signal = sp.signal.fftconvolve(in_signal, self._coeffs, 'full')[out_signal.size]
else:
    for index in np.ndindex(original_shape[1:]):
        slice_index = (slice(None),) + index
        out_signal[slice_index] = sp.signal.fftconvolve(
            in_signal[slice_index], self._coeffs, 'full')[:original_shape[0]]

return out_signal
```

Can I use something instead of using `fftconvolve`?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a multidimensional data through a one dimensional filter? Are you trying to pass a 1D filter for each dimension? Not sure about the question.

Comment: Could you give us some example input/output?

Comment: @Ivan : I want to pass a multidimensional signal through an 1D filter.

Comment: @ali_m: I've just added some code.

Comment: Could you turn your code snippet into a proper function, and show how to generate some example input arrays? It is much easier for us to suggest alternatives if we can check that our output is equivalent to that of your original code.

Comment: I can do it only tomorrow.

Comment: As you saw in an answer to [your SciPy issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4744), there is [another SciPy issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3525) where people are working on an `axis` argument which should do what you want. If you can't wait, you can in the meantime use [nitime.utils.fftconvolve()](http://nipy.org/nitime/api/generated/nitime.utils.html#nitime.utils.fftconvolve), which already has the `axis` argument. Of course, the solution suggested by @DavidTrevelyan should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [numpy.apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
out_signal = numpy.apply_along_axis(convolve1d, axis, in_signal)
```

where the function convolve1d is:

```
def convolve1d(array1d):
    return sp.signal.fftconvolve(array1d, self._coeffs, 'full')
```

Alternatively (thanks to the comment by Matthias below), you could do it in one line with apply_along_axis's *args and **kwargs inputs:

```
out_signal = numpy.apply_along_axis(convolve1d, axis, in_signal,
                                    self._coeffs, 'full')
```

Comment: This is syntactically neater, but probably not much quicker than using a standard `for` loop, since `np.apply_along_axis` still does its looping in Python rather than C.

Comment: Since `apply_along_axis()` takes `*args` and `**kwargs`, you might be able to do it without defining a custom function: `out_signal = numpy.apply_along_axis(sp.signal.fftconvolve, axis, in_signal, self._coeffs, 'full')`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of result you need out of a 2D array or matrix, you can do something like sum the columns and 1D FFT the resulting row vector, or sum the rows and 1D FFT the resulting column vector.

Comment: Based on the wording, I think the OP wants to vectorize applying a 1D convolution along a single dimension of an ND array, yielding an ND output rather than 1D.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `in_signal` is 2 dimensional and you're interested in applying the convolution in the last dimension, you can do the following:

```
temp_coeffs = np.repeat(self._coeffs[np.newaxis,:],len(in_signal),0)
out_signal = sp.signal.fftconvolve(in_signal,temp_coeffs,mode='same',axes=-1)
```